# Solutions to build a lightweight and heavily database-driven website?

Tags: php, mysql, database, frameworks, content-management-system

I'm looking for some kind of CMS or framework + ORM (I don't really know exactly what I'm looking for). 
My goal is to build a web app to view and manage database records. 
To help understand, I would like some sort of end-user phpmyadmin/CMS hybrid with minimal programming efforts. In fact, that is to build a database of a particular kind of products, where those are submitted and consulted by end user and validated by myself.

I first thought that wordpress + plugins, mediawiki + semantic or drupal could be quick solutions but

1. those are quite heavy for the purpose.
2. Playing with tons of plugins don't reassure me, as they can become unmaintained, conflicting, ..
3. Solutions like [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) requires bunch of time to write templates, etc..

Then I thought at using a framework (let's say [symfony](http://symfony.com/)) but it's also very time-consuming (compared to an almost out-of-the-box solution). 
Finaly, I thought that the quickest solution may be to develop it all by myself using an easy ORM (like [RedBean](http://redbeanphp.com/)), but I wish I could find a quicker solution.

Any idea ?

*Note: I intend to use a **php/mysql** solution.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of "micro-frameworks" for PHP that work very well with RedBean (which I love btw). It's a compromise between writing everything from scratch and using a full blown framework. I find their is a good degree of flexability using these small(ish) tool kits.

One I've used a little bit is [**Slim**](http://www.slimframework.com/), which gives you routing and some other small things a controller would.

Other similar "micro-frameworks" like Slim:

- [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)
- [Limonade](http://limonade-php.github.com/)
- [GluePHP](http://gluephp.com/) (which is about 30 lines of code)

These all give you routing and some other neat tools. In regards to MVC, they sorta give you the C.

If RedBean is your Model, or the M, all your missing is the V, should you want the whole MVC organization.

For that you can use [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), or any other templating tool.

I personally love working with these components separately, because I find that they are all highly specialized, integrate nicely, and allow me to control to what extent they are in charge of things. The downside is is that they may have compatibility issues with each other and that you have to maintain three, as oppose to one, third-party library to update and depend on their development.

Here's [a good article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/rapid-application-prototyping-in-php-using-a-micro-framework/) on using Slim with [Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm) (an ORM) and Twig, though I find Idiorm rather nasty to work with.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll go with GluePHP or Silex for the routing/controller matching (can't yet decide which one), and RedBean as ORM. 
Anyway, thanks for the extensive answer !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use: 
asp.net + mvc or django

Sorry these are two different comparable environments that should help with not a lot of overhead on learning, and can function quite well with mysql

Comment: Thanks for the advice, though I did not wrote it on the question and just put the tags, I have to use php and mysql (first, It's what I know, and it's what I can host). I edited the question.